# Unable to intercept the code of my remote control at 433 MHz with RaspberryPi

Tags: arduino, rf, raspberry-pi, radio, 433mhz

I'm trying to reproduce the `code` generated by my universal 4-channel `radio control` with `RaspberryPI`.

1. I cloned my remote with a universal remote like this:
2. I used the libraries included in `433Utils` to test my transmitter and receiver components and `work properly.

I'm using:

```
Transmitter: MX-FS-03V (3.5 - 12V DC)
Receiver: MX-05V (5V DC)
Transmission power: 10mW / Frequency: 433MHz
```

But when I try to read the code registered in my remote control using the `RFSniffer` library, I don't receive any data.
Instead I tried using [rpi-rf](https://github.com/milaq/rpi-rf), if I send a code using the [443Utils](https://github.com/ninjablocks/433Utils) `send` tool, I can read it (with noise).

If I use it with my remote control I can't find any code that makes sense for me:

```
    //the result of a long-pressed key

    2019-12-19 23:17:34 - [INFO] receive: Listening for codes on GPIO 27
    2019-12-19 23:17:39 - [INFO] receive: 992 [pulselength 454, protocol 3]
    2019-12-19 23:17:44 - [INFO] receive: 512 [pulselength 375, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:44 - [INFO] receive: 64 [pulselength 384, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:44 - [INFO] receive: 256 [pulselength 379, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:44 - [INFO] receive: 128 [pulselength 376, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:44 - [INFO] receive: 64 [pulselength 379, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:44 - [INFO] receive: 512 [pulselength 1180, protocol 2]
    2019-12-19 23:17:44 - [INFO] receive: 514 [pulselength 382, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:44 - [INFO] receive: 128 [pulselength 380, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:45 - [INFO] receive: 1540 [pulselength 380, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:45 - [INFO] receive: 1990 [pulselength 380, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:45 - [INFO] receive: 2082 [pulselength 381, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:45 - [INFO] receive: 4 [pulselength 530, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:45 - [INFO] receive: 1152 [pulselength 381, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:45 - [INFO] receive: 130 [pulselength 380, protocol 1]
    2019-12-19 23:17:45 - [INFO] receive: 2 [pulselength 378, protocol 1]
    .....
```

My only idea is that the `RFSniffer` library is NOT able to identify the communication protocol of my remote control.

How can I find the code?

**************************`[EDIT: STEP 2]`****************************

I used Audacity to view the wave that is being produced by my signal receiver when I press the button on the remote control. To do reverse engineering of the communication protocol.

[image]

How do I decode the signal (without knowing the protocol and the clock)?

Comment: No Scope? Use the audio AUX input with a software scope

Comment: I didn't understand, can you explain me?

Comment: If you can't decode the noise, look at it with a scope

Comment: The problem is not the noise, I can't identify the code I'm looking for.. 
anyway, how can i look at noise with a scope?

Comment: what is the `universal 4-channel radio control`? ... which universal remote did you use to clone it?

Comment: _"My only idea is that the RFSniffer library is NOT able to identify the communication protocol of my remote control."_ - that is the logical conclusion. _"How can I find the code?"_ - no idea. You might have to write your own decoder!

Comment: Or even write your own encoder

Comment: @jsotola I used a unversal remote like this (https://www.amazon.it/gp/product/B00OPYYKXK/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o04_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) to verify that the code was not dynamic and therefore could be cloned.
Then I tried both with the original and with the universal. for neither of them I get what I expect.

Comment: @BruceAbbott To help me understand how to write the decoder: should I read exactly what I get from the component without using libraries?
or: should I work on the data I receive (code, pulselength, protocol)?

Comment: The data produced by rfsniffer doesn't look useful to me. I would start by looking at the actual waveform, then determine the bit protocol from it. This is more likely to get good results than randomly trying different libraries in the hope of finding one that works. Plus you learn more, and it's fun! https://fetzerch.github.io/2014/11/15/reveng433/

Comment: @BruceAbbott This is exactly what I want to do!
Considering that this is my first experience, initially I tried what I had available, to avoid reinventing the wheel: D

Thank you for the link ! it is what i'm looking for !

I will update on the results and about my fun XD

Comment: @BruceAbbott I tried to do what you suggested, I get a signal using AUX. I can't understand how I have to decode the wave. I'm going to add the wave image in the question.